# When I take the user input, I want to search my array and get the results

Tags: java

```
String s;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a country");

s = sc.nextLine();
s = (callWebService.getTemperature("s"));

System.out.println("The city temperature is "+s);
```

What I have here is asking the user for input and I want to get the user input and search in my array like a 2D array to get results from the second column.

For example: entering the country name and getting the temperature.

This is what I have here and stuck with the implementation

```
public String getTemperature(String one) {

}
```

Comment: Where is your array and how is it defined? What data does it hold? Please update your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having. Oh, and welcome to SO! :)

Comment: Could you add the part where you're reading from the array. And why do you have a callWebService?

Comment: Consider using a Map rather than a 2D array

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the 2D array and if the if the 1st column item is equal to the user input, take the value of the second column in the same row

```
for(int i=0; i <=array.length(); i++){
    if (array[i][0] == input){        
        temperature = array[i][1]
    }
}
```